# ASP Classic Connection to SQL Server 2008 error 80004005 Login Failed

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I'm trying to setup a connection between ASP Classic and SQL Server 2008 Express on a Windows 7 local environment. Today has been my first attempt ever at this, and I have spent hours and hours researching to no avail. The best I can do is get a failed login.

Here's the connection string (one of many tried):

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=mycompname\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=theDBName;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

The error:

> *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'*
>
> *Cannot open database "theDBName" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.*

What I want:

Just anything that will connect a database to my ASP Classic page (I normally work in LAMP)! This is not for a live site, so for the time being, that's my only consideration. Just getting it done. :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified Integrated Security=SSPI, which means that the user owning the process making the connection must be allowed access to the database. That means that the web service must have access. Have you done that?

It might be easier if you create a named user, give it a password, and use that in your connection string.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and added "UID=myusername;PWD=mypwd" to the string. The error is now "Login failed for myusername" with code 80040e4d.

Comment: I presume you added 'myusername' to the server and gave them access to that database? Also, do you have a firewall active on the PC, and could it be interfering?

Comment: I did what you mentioned, but I will check the firewall now.

Comment: Another thing, to confirm that you can connect to the database with that user, try to create an ODBC connection from the Control Panel and test the connection. If you can, then you have a network connection/permissions problem. Actually, that's something: try adding Server=localhost\sqlexpress,1433 to force TCP/IP (and check out [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Comment: Thanks again. I tried going into Control Panel for your ODBC suggestion. It gave me a couple options for drivers (SQL Server and SQL Server Native Client 10.0) when I tried setting up user DSN but at the test portion, both failed to connect. I also tried the TCP/IP solution to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like you need to go back to basics and get those connections working first; then you might have a fighting chance of getting Classic ASP talking to the database! Good luck...

Comment: Hi there. I didn't have time to work out what was wrong with my connection, but I switched to MySQL and managed to make it work out. Thanks for trying to help, though. I'll give it a shot another day.

Comment: No worries, some days are like that. It will probably "just work" next time you try :)